# Elixir - testing a full script

Tags: testing, pattern-matching, elixir, phoenix-framework, gen-server

I'm writing a test to check a function (called automatically by GenServer when a new file enters a folder) that calls other functions in the same module with pipes in order to read a file, process its content to insert it if needed and returns a list (:errors and :ok maps).

results looks like :

```
[
          error: "Data not found",
          ok: %MyModule{
            field1: field1data,
            field2: field2data
          },
          ok: %MyModule{
            field1: field1data,
            field2: field2data
          },
          error: "Data not found"
```

the code :

```
  def processFile(file) do
    insertResultsMap =
      File.read!(file)
      |> getLines()
      |> extractMainData()
      |> Enum.map(fn(x) -> insertLines(x) end)
      |> Enum.group_by(fn x -> elem(x, 0) end)

    handleErrors(Map.get(insertResultsMap, :error))
    updateAnotherTableWithLines(Map.get(insertResultsMap, :ok))
  end

  defp getLines(docContent) do
    String.split(docContent, "\n")
  end

  defp extractMainData(docLines) do
    Enum.map(fn(x) -> String.split(x, ",") end)
  end

  defp insertLines([field1, field2, field3, field4]) do
    Attrs =  %{
      field1: String.trim(field1),
      field2: String.trim(field2),
      field3: String.trim(field3),
      field4: String.trim(field4)
    }

    mymodule.create_stuff(Attrs)
  end

  defp handleErrors(errors) do
    {:ok, file} = File.open(@errorsFile, [:append])
    saveErrors(file, errors)
    File.close(file)
  end

  defp saveErrors(_, []), do: :ok
  defp saveErrors(file, [{:error, changeset}|rest]) do
    changes = for {key, value} <- changeset.changes do
      "#{key} #{value}"
    end
    errors = for {key, {message, _}} <- changeset.errors do
      "#{key} #{message}"
    end

    errorData = "data: #{Enum.join(changes, ", ")} \nErrors: #{Enum.join(errors, ", ")}\n\n"

    IO.binwrite(file, errorData)
    saveErrors(file, rest)
  end

  defp updateAnotherTableWithLines(insertedLines) do
    Enum.map(insertedLines, fn {:ok, x} -> updateOtherTable(x) end)
  end

  defp updateOtherTable(dataForUpdate) do
    "CLOSE" -> otherModule.doStuff(dataForUpdate.field1, dataForUpdate.field2)
  end
```

I have several questions, and some will be pretty basic since I'm still learning :

- What do you think of the code ? Any advices ? (take into account I voluntarily obfuscated names).
- If I want to test this, is it the right way to test only `processFile` function ? Or should I make public more of them and test them individually ?
- When I test the `processFile` function, I check that I'm receiving a list. Any way to make sure this list has only elements I'm waiting for, thus `error: "String"` or `ok: %{}`" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you think of the code? Any advices? (take into account I voluntarily obfuscated names).

Opinion based.

> If I want to test this, is it the right way to test only processFile function?

Yes.

> Or should I make public more of them and test them individually?

No, this is an implementation detail and testing it is an anti-pattern.

> When I test the processFile function, I check that I'm receiving a list. Any way to make sure this list has only elements I'm waiting for, thus error: "String" or ok: %{}"?

You receive a `Keyword`. To check the explicit value, one might use:

```
foo = processFile(file)
assert not is_nil(foo[:ok])
```

OTOH, I’d better return a map from there and pattern match it:

```
assert %{ok: _} = processFile(file)
```

---

To assert that the result does not have anything save for `:ok`s and `:error`s, one might use list subtraction:

```
assert Enum.uniq(Keyword.keys(result)) -- [:ok, :error] == []
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping. Moving to a map would remove the duplicate keys, wouldn't it ? Also, I don't want to test that returned `keyword` actually contains any `:ok` tuple, but rather that it doesn't contain something unexpected - other that `:ok` and `:error` tuples.

Comment: 1. yes, if you need duplicate keys, `Keyword` is the way to go. 2. Then simply assert `Keyword.keys(result) -- ~w|ok error|a == []`.

Comment: This won't work - as per doc def "Removes the first occurrence of an item on the left list for each item on the right" - only the first ! To remove all occurences of `:ok` and `:error` it won't work. Converting to a `MapSet` would remove some elements... But then, I could convert to a map and bind to a new variable in order to check only expected elements' keys are here, without relying on this new variable for anything else :) Thanks again